# How to compare lists using apex

Tags: apex, list

I have Two List of object records.

```
List<Account> accList1 = [Select id from Account limit 4];
List<Account> accList2 = [Select id from Account limit 3];
```

I have another `List<Account> accList3 = new List<Account>()`
now I want to compare both List `accList1`  and `accList2` , get the record from `accList1` which is not present in `accList2`  and add to `accList3`.

Comment: This would probably be easier if you use `Map<Id, Account>`, so you can use the `removeAll()` method from the Set class on the key set of the map.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you would like to perform difference operations you can use the `Set` collection for it.

```
Set<String> list1 = new Set<String> {'a', 'b', 'c'};
Set<String> list2 = new Set<String> {'a', 'c'};
Set<String> list3 = new Set<String>(list1);
list3.removeAll(list2);

System.debug('list3: ' + list3);
```

Result is:

> |DEBUG|list3: {b}

---

Important note, that if you want to use non-immutable values (objects) in sets (key of maps) you need to make sure, that for this object `hashCode` and `equals` are defined. For SObjects it is done by salesforce automatically.

---

In the current example, I recommend extracting ids of accounts, do `removeAll` and you will receive as a result set of ids of accounts, which are present in the `list1`, but not present in `list2`

Answer (score -1):

The other approach would look like below:

To go with Lists:

```
List<Account> list1 = new List<Account>([Select id from Account limit 4]);
List<Account> list2 = new List<Account>([Select id from Account limit 3]);
List<Account> list3 = new List<Account>();

for(Account o : list1){
  if(!list2.contains(o) ){
      //your logic
      list3.add(o);
  }
}
```

To go with Sets:

```
Set<Account> set1 = new Set<Account>([Select id from Account limit 4]);
Set<Account> set2 = new Set<Account>([Select id from Account limit 3]);
Set<Account> set3 = new Set<Account>();

for(Account o : set1){
  if(!set2.contains(o) ){
      //your logic
      set3.add(o);
  }
}
```

Use it according to your business use case.

Answer (score -2):

1. Query records and store in 2 list.
2. Declare the third list.
3. Iterate over first list element and check whether it is available in second list.
4. Add to third list if first list element is not available in second list.

[image: Code]

Believe you have to use list for some reason. Hope the above code was useful.

Comment: Please do not post code as images.